# Is there a way to query over a range based key cached object in django redis cache?

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework, django-cache, redis-cache

I'm working on a game server matchmaking and I have a room object which has a range that has two field and other extra fields :

```
min_score = IntegerField (help = 'minimum score that user should have to join this room.')
max_score = IntegerField (help = 'maximum score that a user can have to join this room.')
```

I'm going to cache this object and then if a user requests to join a room with a range that users can join.
Is there a way that I can do something like below query on redis-cache?

```
Room.objects.filter(min_score__lte=user.score, max_score__gte=user.score)
```

I already have some algorithms that should do `.get('key')` `n` times.
But I wonder if there's a better solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes deleted by stackoverflow: checkout https://redis.io/commands/zadd

Answer (score 0):

You can split this up in two filters, like:

```
Room.objects.filter(min_score__lte=user.score, max_score__gte=user.score)
```

We thus specify that the `min_score` is smaller than or equal to `user.score`, and the `max_score` is greater than or equal to `user.score`.

Here we use the [**`__lte`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lte) and [**`__gte`** lookups [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte). You can use [**`__lt`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt) and [**`__gt`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt) if you want the ranges to be exclusive.

By using a `db_index`, you probably can boost the lookup a bit more:

```
from django.db import models

class Room(models.Model):
    min_score = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    max_score = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
```

Comment: As I mentioned on the question I would like to cache this object by django-redis cache and I don't want it to be on my db. So I can't run queries with objects like Room.objects.filter(...) and I can just use cache methods like cache.get('key') but I can use your response to make my question more clear.